# How To Edit After Effects Template with Python or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, visualization, video-processing, after-effects

I planning to build an online music visualizer but I cannot figure out how to generate high graphic visualization using this After Effects template - [Visualization After Effects Template](https://www.velosofy.com/template/neon-moon-audio-visualizer-gwhef28c28o) and similar others. How can I Edit this Template with my own text and audio.
I want to make something like this - [Website Example](https://www.renderforest.com/music-visualisations)

I Found Some Visualization Example using Web Audio & p5js But They Were Not as Graphically Pleasing and I want to Streamline The Process By Using Existing AE Templates.
I Was Not Able to Find Any Helpful Tutorial or Tool for this, So I am Here Looking for a Solution.

The Process -

1. User Makes API Request with Link of Audio (web address), Title and Subtitle.
2. The Video is Processed with the Data in the request and stored in a public access dir.
3. Link to The File is Sent Back to The User.

The Tech I Am Open to Use :
ReactJS, Javascript, Python, Django, Nodejs.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Not clear... **(1)** You have Adobe After Effects and want to use it to render videos from user data? Or **(2)** you want to recreate the same visualization using Javascript? Anyways a template is just a text file so you edit it as you edit any text of a String variable.

Comment: I want to edit the template using javascript or python and render out a video file. The Things Needed to be edited - Audio and Some Text including title and subtitle

Comment: The First Option

Comment: **(1)** Decide which programming language you're going to use for this and [**update your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63361208/edit) when stuck. **(2)** To get a fast answer, show what you want to change and how, show your code attempt for that and we'll try help to fix it. **(3)** If possible get a tool like `Notepad++` and open your template there. It will show the text character positions then you can know which **exact** position your code should use to find the text you want to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NexRender](https://github.com/inlife/nexrender)

This Will Help To Edit and Render After Effects File.
Read the Docs and Implement According to Your Need.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add this in addition to Shivam's answer:  you can achieve this using Dataclay's tool [Templater Bot for Adobe After Effects](https://dataclay.com/templater).